# How to calculate highest total sales for the last month of data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have one dataframe name as **store_data.csv** having thousands of data in the dataframe. Sample Data is like this-

```
Date       Store1   Store2   Store3   Store4
2018-06-01 2643     1642     2678     3050
2018-07-16 6442     5413     5784     7684
2018-07-24 4587     5743     3948     6124
2018-08-12 3547     8743     7462     8315
```

How to calculate which store highest total sales for the last month of data in python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `DatetimeIndex`:

```
#if necessary
#df = df.set_index('Date')
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

print (df)
            Store1  Store2  Store3  Store4
Date                                      
2018-06-01    2643    1642    2678    3050
2018-07-16    6442    5413    5784    7684
2018-08-10    4587    5743    3948    6124 <-change date for better sample
2018-08-12    3547    8743    7462    8315

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-06-01', '2018-07-16', '2018-08-10', '2018-08-12'], 
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Then convert to month period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(df.index.to_period('M'))
print (df1)
         Store1  Store2  Store3  Store4
Date                                   
2018-06    2643    1642    2678    3050
2018-07    6442    5413    5784    7684
2018-08    4587    5743    3948    6124
2018-08    3547    8743    7462    8315
```

Filter by last value, `sum` and last get column name by max value by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
print (df1.loc[df1.index[-1]].sum())
Store1     8134
Store2    14486
Store3    11410
Store4    14439
dtype: int64

out = df1.loc[df1.index[-1]].sum().idxmax()
print (out)
Store2
```

Thank you, @Jon Clements for another solution:

```
out = df.last('M').resample('M').sum().T.idxmax()
#if need scalar output
out = df.last('M').resample('M').sum().iloc[0].idxmax()
```

Comment: may I know why giving `-1` ? for last index ?

Comment: @pyd - There is datetimeindex? Maybe need `df = df.set_index('Date')`

Comment: @pyd - I know now, I change data only.

Comment: I am getting `TypeError` for `(df1.loc[df1.index[-1]].sum())`

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate it is or if it's any better... but starting with your example `df` where it's got a `DateTimeIndex`, you can do: `df.last('M').resample('M').sum().T.idxmax()` and work with that... might allow easier time pickings so you can do "last 30 days" by month or "last 3 months by week" or similar instead of using index offsets and such... not tested it fully though but thought it worth mentioning...

Comment: So: `df.last('M').resample('D').sum().T.idxmax()` will give you the best performing stores by day in the last month for instance... (or something like that but probably need to cater for either filling/handling filled values in the resample...)

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for answer my problem. But i am getting an error `'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_period'`

Comment: @MdWasi - So need `df = df.set_index('Date')` and `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` for DatetimeIndex in first step.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is specific to your problem and a bit hacky, but I've tested it and it seems to be working for me.

This program will find the store with the highest amount of sales during the last month. This program assumes that months are given in order (the data isn't mixed). If this is a problem, please modify the question to be a bit more specific and I'll see what I can do. One possible implementation for this would be to keep track of each month using a `dictionary` and then access the last month's data to find the max.

```
import re

def get_highest_sales(filename):
    sales_during_month = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    with open(filename) as f:
        f.readline() # Skip first line
        prev_month = ""
        for line in f:
            cleaned = re.sub(" +", ' ', line)
            values = cleaned.split(' ')
            month  = values[0].split('-')[1]
            if not month == prev_month:
                prev_month = month
                sales_during_month = [0, 0, 0, 0]
            sales = [float(sale) for sale in values[1:]]
            for store,sale in enumerate(sales):
                sales_during_month[store] += sale

    return "Store: " + str(sales_during_month.index(max(sales_during_month)) + 1)
```